# Br tag in rails view slim syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

In the below slim code how can I add a br tag after the =@store_params[i]

```
th Department  
    - 0.upto(@store_length) do |i|  
        th style="text-align: left;" =@store_params[i]
```

Comment: Why do you want to put <br> tagsbetween table column headers? Would that, if it worked, put each column heading on a separate line?

Answer (score 2):

I have a lot of problems with that too...
Have you tried this?

EDIT: I'm sorry, I forgot to indent properly the br under th.

```
 th Department  
    - 0.upto(@store_length) do |i|  
        th style="text-align: left;" =@store_params[i]
          br
```

Comment: Hi Jordão, the "\n" will error. The first option will add a break but not in the th. My initial thought was to add a br tag in the th and some other text so that I will wrap the th content where I want to. For now I will try to follow another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear why one would want to put `<br>` tags between table column headers.  Column headers should flow horizontally across the window and HTML appears to force that to happen whether the `<br>` tag is there or not. However, if that is absolutely what you want to do, the following should do it for you:

```
table
  th Department  
  - 0.upto(@store_length) do |i|  
    th style="text-align: left;" #{store_params[i]}
      <br>
```

I think `slim` may be ignoring the un-bracketed `br` because it is not expecting it.